# SvelteKit handle cookie change and refresh data?

Tags: cookies, hook, refresh, svelte, sveltekit

I have an hook.server.ts to handle auth cookie:

```
import type { Handle } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { SECRET_JWT_TOKEN } from "$env/static/private";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { getUsers } from "$lib/configs/users";

const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  const authCookie = event.cookies.get("AuthorizationToken");

  if (authCookie) {
    // Remove Bearer prefix
    const token = authCookie.split(" ")[1];

    try {
      const jwtUser = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_JWT_TOKEN);
      if (typeof jwtUser === "string") {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }

      const user = await getUsers().then((users) =>
        users.find((user) => user.email === jwtUser.email)
      );

      if (!user) {
        throw new Error("User not found");
      }

      const sessionUser = {
        email: user.email,
        role: user.type,
      };

      event.locals.user = sessionUser;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return await resolve(event);
};

export { handle };
```

On my routes folder i have an +layout.server.ts to verify user permissions based on locals that were saved by hook.

```
import { UserTypes, type User } from "$lib/configs";
import { getUsers } from "$lib/configs/users";
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from "./$types";

export const load = (async ({locals}) => {
  let users: User[] = await getUsers();

  const { user } = locals;
  let userRole;

  if (user === undefined) {
    userRole = UserTypes.GUEST;
  } else {
    userRole = user.role;
  }

  return {
    users: users,
    userRole: userRole
  };
}) satisfies LayoutServerLoad;
```

In my pages i use data.userRole to verify the type of user:

```
{#if data.userRole !== UserTypes.GUEST}
    <div
      class="p-2.5 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-white"
    >
      <i class="fa-solid fa-gear" />
      <span class="hidden md:inline text-[15px] ml-4 font-bold">Settings</span>
    </div>
    <a
      href="/logout"
      data-sveltekit-preload-data="off"
      data-sveltekit-reload
      class="p-2.5 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-white"
    >
      <i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket" />
      <span class="hidden md:inline text-[15px] ml-4 font-bold">Logout</span>
    </a>
  {/if}
```

But the problem is when cookie change or is deleted manually, because page still working as logged in user!

I tried to create an variable on top of handle function:

```
...

let isAuth = false;
const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {

...

  if (authCookie) {
    
     ...

     isAuth = true;
  }


  if(!authCookie && isAuth) {
    console.log("No auth");
    event.locals.user = undefined;
    throw redirect(302,"/");
  }
}
```